# SQLite and an C# program

Tags: c#, sqlite

I like to use an database for my program, and I ran into SQLite.

At my first look, SQLite looks great. But there's only one thing.

I don't want that users must install SQLite in order to run the program.

Now did I see that I can download the source code of it.

So my question to you guys is... Can I compile the SQLite server into my program, and then use the server like normal? And when you stop the program, the server stops also??? Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite doesn't use a server, it's just a DLL reference and a shared file format. It is the best choice for what you are trying to do.

Check this library out: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki , http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Comment: so if i understand it right.... I can use the System.Data.SQlite, and an db file, and everything works just fine???

Comment: Yep! It's that easy :) I've used this a lot and it's surprisingly fast and you even get features like journaling and transactions. It's perfect for small projects where you don't want to be intrusive to the client machine.

Comment: Sounds nice, Thanks you for the clear answer and the links ;-)

Comment: And what version (download link) would you suggest if i want to keep the program 32 bit and 64 bit compatible? (windows)

Comment: That depends on your target system. If you don't plan on using more than 4 GB of ram you can use the 32-bit one and it'll run on 64-bit as well. You can also use any CPU to compile and add the 32-bit one.

Comment: alright, so it will be the 32 bit... And what sould i do, the precompiled binaries or the setup version??? (sorry for all the questions)

Comment: Never mind, i've used the setup :P Thank you verry much for your help (A)

Answer (score 2):

There is no such concept like `SqLite` server.

For deploying `SqLite`, to client machine for you it's enough to deploy `C#` drivers to be able to connect to that DB (you can download them from [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)), and DB file itself (in case when  you don't create it at runtime).

In other words, there is nothing to install, there is no any service to start.

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is an "Embedded Database".
SQL Server Express can be embedded, so that your users don't need to install the server. They will just need the data file.

Comment: SQLite is far better and more portable than SQL embedded or LocalDB.